# ¿Cómo prevenir ir a Activity anterior en Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy creando una splash screen para una aplicación en Android

Parto de un activity `.myIntro` y llamo la activity `.mainActivity` desde allí, en `mainActivity` detecto el evento `backPressed` para si se pulsa ir atrás, finalice la activity con `finish();`

Pero me encuentro que, me vuelve hacia `myIntro` haciendo bucle, si se va deprisa mientra está la activity `myIntro` en pantalla, pulsando atrás sale de la app.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="devtest.welcomescreen">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyIntro"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyIntro.java** llamo la activity principal

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**MainActivity.java** detectar evento volver atrás

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("MainActivity","onBackPressed()");
    finish();
}
```

¿Cómo sería para cerrar definitivamente la aplicación justo en mainActivity? 
independientemente de las actividades que estén cargadas anteriormente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al realizar un intent desde tu `Activity` "intro" y no deseas tenerla en la pila de actividades, siempre se debe terminar la actividad con [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);

 finish(); //Elimina de la pila de Actividades.
```

`finish()` ejecuta `onDestroy()`, eliminando la actividad de la memoria. Aquí el ciclo de vida de la Actividad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo he solucionado, en `MyIntro.java`cuando se llama la carga del acitvity `MainActivity.java` se tiene que agregar `finish()`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

y en el `MainActivity` se puede retirar el `override de onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 2):

Tambien podrias agregar los flags para que al presionar atras salga de la aplicacion

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```