# Cómo abrir una página web desde una aplicación Android?

Tags: java, android, app

Ya utilice la informacion de https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html (por cierto muy buena):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Probando en el emulador, ya me abre el navegador web de android con la pagina web que necesito, pero al cerrarlo, se observa la layout del activity que tengo creado, sera que deberia modificarlo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Soy muy nuevo en android, estoy comenzando hoy, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Osea, no quieres que al cerrar el navegador se habra tu app?

Comment: @EinerSantana quiero que al cerrar el navegador se cierre la referencia del layout de la app que esta quedando abierta, pero ya lo resolvi, haciendo un  finish(); //Elimina de la pila de Actividades.

Comment: Para que no me mantuviera el Layout del activity aplique lo referente a esta respuesta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3427/c%C3%B3mo-prevenir-ir-a-activity-anterior-en-android/3436#3436] usando un finish(); //Elimina de la pila de Actividades. al final del metodo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cómo abrir una página web desde una aplicación Android?**

Para realizar esto es precisamente mediante un `Intent` :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.mipagina.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

Pero si lo que deseas es abrirla dentro de la aplicación, agrega un `WebView` para cargar dentro la página web. Agrega un `WebView` a tu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">



    <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Agrega el siguiente permiso dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml para permitir conexión a internet dentro de tu aplicación.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Para cargar la página, agrega el siguiente código dentro de tu método `onCreate()`, obtén la referencia del WebView dentro del layout, habilita javascript (la mayoria de las páginas hacen uso de javascript para su correcto funcionamiento), y carga la url dentro del WebView.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

De esta forma cargarias sin problema la página dentro de tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo @Jorgesys Gracias por tu respuesta, en el articulo de [https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html] comentan lo que me dices y me parece bien, pero también en este articulo [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html] hacen referencia de que si es una web de interacción constante se debería usar un Intent.ACTION_VIEW, de igual forma voy a hacer la app también con un WebView y hacer las respectivas pruebas, a ver cual es la mas conveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer uso de WebView

```
<WebView                    
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

En tu codigo declarar una variable de tipo WebView:

```
public WebView explorer;
```

Hacer referencia al objeto:

```
WebView explorer = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Configuramos las opciones del navegador (en este caso habilitar javascript):

```
WebSettings webSettings = explorer.getSettings ();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
```

Declaramos la variable dirección (url):

```
String direcion1 ="....." ;
```

Configuramos el webview para anexar la dirección a mostrar, para posteriormente ejecutar la url y mostrar el contenido.

```
        explorer.loadUrl(direcion1);
        explorer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        explorer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        explorer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.